# Build all strings where each digit is a charachter from a set

Tags: java, recursion

If I have a two dimensional String array of charachters

`{{"A", "B", "C"},{"D", "E", F"} ... {"P", "Q", "R"}, {"S", "T", "W"}}`

Then how would I build a string with the length of the main array, and each digit is a charachter from the inner array? For example, the output would be

`"ADG...PS", "ADG...PT, "ADG...PW",  "ADG...QS" ...`.

To do it without recursion, I would need `n` nested for loops, where `n` is the length of the main array. I can't hard code that however.

I think the base case would be the last string, like `C, F, ..., R, S`
and you would start from `"ADG...PS"`, and increment it somehow, but I can't figure out how to implement this. I know that in python there is a library to do so, but I need to do this in java.

Comment: I am slightly confused, you need to do this with recursion?

Comment: Are you asking how to do it _with_ recursion, or _without_ recursion?  Both are possible, but _with_ recursion is much easier.

Comment: I'm trying to do it with recursion

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is indeed the answer, but not recursion among the strings in the result set, but recursion along the characters within a result string.

Put in a less abstract way: All result strings of length n can be formed by taking a result string of length n-1, and appending a possible last character.

In code:

```
List<String> generateStrings(String[][] possibleCharacters, int index) {
    if (index < 0) {
        return new ArrayList<>("");
    } else {
        var results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (var s : generateStrings(possibleCharacters, index - 1)) {
            for (var c : possibleCharacters[index]) {
                results.add(s + c);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Efficiency purists would frown on the repeated String concatenations. To avoid that, we can use a single `StringBuilder` to build all Strings:

```
void generateStrings(String[][] possibleCharacters, StringBuilder prefix, List<String> results) {
    var index = prefix.length();
    if (index == possibleCharacters.length) {
        results.add(prefix.toString());
    } else {
        for (String c : possibleCharacters[index]) {
          prefix.append(c);
          generateStrings(possibleCharacters, prefix, results);
          prefix.delete(index, prefix.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Another possible problem is that the list of generated strings gets really big really quick, so storing them all in memory before processing them might be considered wasteful. In phython, you'd use a generator for that. In Java, the closest semantic equivalent would be a `Stream`, but they are hard to provide, so a simple callback is probably the better choice. That is, rather than passing a `List<String>` to receive the results, you'd pass a `Consumer<String>` that is to be invoked for every result.

Comment: There seems to be many errors with your second code, I can't compile it in intelliJ. What is the most efficient method?

Comment: Fixed. And I believe I already mentioned that the second method is marginally more efficient (but harder to understand).